# Having hard time understanding memoization

Tags: javascript, node.js, scripting, memoization

Recently, I was reading 'The good parts' and was going through a topic called **memoization** but I couldn't understand it properly. What I did not get is, won't it be a memory consuming way like keeping a variable with a lot of data in case the function is executing a high number of time. If this is the case, than how is it optimization. Please note that, I am new to java script and I have read about this topic.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization... lookout for ppts available on the web and start modestly, search meanings of various terminologies used, then further you can enhance them.
All the best.

Comment: Why minus, is it that obvious???

Comment: Its not that obvious that we expect you to understand. But you should have put some efforts into the question before asking here. If you dont understand a concept, tell us what your confusion is. Dont just ask "What is this?"

Comment: @Vishwanath i wil edit my question

Comment: Precisely.. thats the whole point...you are permitted to ask limited questions only. So choose wisely what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

Memoization is a simple mechanism that consist in caching the result of computed values.

1. This allows the next function call, done with the same parameters,
   to hit the cache rather than re-computing this values.
2. The cache is indexed by the input arguments. If the arguments exist
   in the cache, then the cached value is returned.
3. Otherwise, the function is executed and the newly computed value is
   added to the cache.

If you understand the caching mechanism, it's very easy to understand memoization.

As far as I know, there are two level of optimizations one can do with their programme:

1. Time Optimization
2. Memory Optimization

It totally depends on the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Remember dynamic programming? While calculating the factorial of a number, you remember the factorial till n-1 and then multiply the fact(n-1) with n. But the problem in some cases is the unnecessary calls, which can easily be avoided.

To save these unnecessary calls, we can memoize it. To save the memoize results, one can use an array, inside a closure. When your function is called, first thing it checks is whether it already has an answer, if yes, then it returns the answer otherwise, it recalculates it.

Comment: Can you provide any example ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know basics of

- prototypal inheritance
- variable scope and
- closure

this [article](http://addyosmani.com/blog/faster-javascript-memoization/) is what you need. but mind that you must be knowing JS concepts mentioned above